# Is there a limitation on the number of tables a PostgreSQL database can have?

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-design, postgresql

I have created a database in PostgreSQL, let's call it **testdb**.

I have a generic set of tables inside this database, **xxx_table_one**, **xxx_table_two** and **xxx_table_three**.

Now, I have Python code where I want to dynamically create and remove "sets" of these 3 tables to my database with a unique identifier in the table name distinguishing different "sets" from each other, e.g.

**Set 1**
testdb.aaa_table_one
testdb.aaa_table_two
testdb.aaa_table_three

**Set 2**
testdb.bbb_table_one
testdb.bbb_table_two
testdb.bbb_table_three

The reason I want to do it this way is to keep multiple LARGE data collections of related data separate from each other. I need to regularly overwrite individual data collections, and it's easy if we can just drop the data collections table and recreate a complete new set of tables. Also, I have to mention, the different data collections fit into the same schemas, so I could save all the data collections in 1 set of tables using an identifier to distinguish data collections instead of separating them by using different tables.

I want to know, a few things

1. Does PostgreSQL limit the number of tables per database?
2. What is the effect on performance, if any, of having a large number of tables in 1 database?
3. What is the effect on performance of saving the data collections in different sets of tables compared to saving them all in the same set, e.g. I guess would need to write more queries if I want to query multiple data collections at once when the data is spread accross tables as compared to just 1 set of tables.

Comment: Define "large". Creating and dropping tables is usually the wrong approach to take.

Comment: Do. Not. Do. This.  It's a dreadful design hack.  Many people try it -- everyone who tries it regrets it.  Use key values as columns inside the tables; do not create tables like this.

Comment: Large could be about 1,000.000 - 10,000,000 records. Not that large, but each data collection is a pre-processed data collection updated once or twice a month.

Comment: Thanks S.Lott. Could you please elaborate a bit on the pitfalls of this design decision? Much appreciated.

Comment: Generating table names dynamically is expensive.  Slow.  Difficult.  You have to build (and parse and execute) SQL statements that aren't all similar.    Putting key values into a column is inexpensive.  Fast.  Simple.  You're just putting values into SQL statements that are pre-parsed and ready to execute with new values.  Do Not Build Tables Names Dynamically.

Comment: After reading this thread I found the following link useful: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have many limits, your hardware is much more limited, that's where you encounter most problems. http://www.postgresql.org/about/

You can have 2^32 tables in a single database, just over 4 billion.

Comment: The conclusion referred in this response is an credit of an research of a PostgreSQL community contributor see [PGCon 2013](http://www.pgcon.org/2013/schedule/attachments/283_Billion_Tables_Project-PgCon2013.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

1. PostgreSQL doesn't impose a direct limit on this, your OS does (it depends on maximum directory size)
2. This may depend on your OS as well. Some filesystems get slower with large directories.
3. PostgreSQL won't be able to optimize queries if they're across different tables. So using less tables (or a single table) should be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

If your data were not related, I think your tables could be in different schema, and then you would use `SET search_path TO schema1, public` for example, this way you wouldn't have to dynamically generate table names in your queries. I am planning to try this structure on a large database which stores logs and other tracking information.

You can also change your `tablespace` if your os has a limit or suffers from large directory size.